# Use 32-bit jni libraries on 64-bit android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, 32bit-64bit

I've tried running an application using a native library on the Nexus 9.

The application exits with an error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "lib_xyz.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
```

Is there any known workaround for this problem (except, of course, recompiling the library and making the apk bigger)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Found an explanation: 64-bit Android can use 32-bit native libraries as a fallback, only if System.loadlLibrary() can't find anything better in the default search path.
You get an UnsatisfiedLinkError if you force the system to load the 32-bit library using System.load() with the full library path.
So the first workaround is using System.loadLibrary() instead of System.load().

An additional thing that has to be taken into account is that libraries cannot be mixed: the fallback behaviour only applies for the first library your application loads. If the first one is 64-bit, no 32-bit libraries can be loaded by the same application, and vice versa.

Comment: Hey G B, is there a source for that?

Comment: Yes. I`ve discovered it by browsing the Android source code (how library loading is implemented)

Comment: @gb I know this is maybe old stuff, but we're finding that after an OS upgrade to Android 5.1.1 on a Galaxy S6 Edge this is not working anymore. Before that it was working. Do you know if this has changed? Can you point out where you found this? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, the reason was other (and something to remember to check in this cases): we added a module to our project which had a dependency to a JNI library. This library has support for 64 bits, and the compatibility fallback gets disabled in this cases.

Comment: @GB Thanks for sharing this insight! would you mind referring me to the exact location in the AOSP source code where you've found the library loading implementation (Preferably on Lollipop or higher). Thanks :)

Comment: The app will try to load the lib*.so in the cpu_architecture folder first! If nothing's found, other lib*.so from other folders will be loaded, one after another.

Comment: How to solve this crash? Any code solution for this issue?

Comment: This does not work for me. I only loaded one 32-bit lib on a arm64-v8a phone. I used System.loadLibrary() instead of System.load(). Yet I still get the error.

Answer (score 19):

the point is to convert the run environment to 32 bit

1. add the follow content in **build.gradle**

   defaultConfig: {
       ...
       ndk {
           abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips" 
       }
   }
2. add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` into **gradle.properties**
3. add new folder named **armeabi** under the libs, then copy a 32bit `.so` file
           into the new folder

Comment: What if I am using CMake instead of NDK builds? How do I use defaultConfig': ndk {abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips" } and android.useDeprecatedNdk=true.

Comment: This was enough for me to stop the crash from happening `ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86" }`

Comment: From where i can download 32bit .so file?

Comment: Will Android block workaround this after Aug '19 as a full 64 bit requirement ?

Comment: From august 1 2019 we have to follow 64 bit guideline as stated in google policy. By doing the above steps play store shows a warning

Comment: yes this also shows error in play store during update or new app publishing time

Comment: @Tarun Not a warning actually, but an ERROR indeed

Answer (score 4):

This work for me:

```
 ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
```

Comment: ooh you are life saver buddy :) Thank you so much

Comment: This worked for me :
ndk { abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips" }

Comment: This works but remember that when you upload your .apk or App bundle, Google Play Store will force you to support 64-bit architecture and you will be forced to add back variants to abiFilters and the problem will also come back

Comment: So what is the solution for this need to upload playstore.

Answer (score 1):

https://source.android.com/source/64-bit-builds.html

Try this in you Android.mk

```
LOCAL_MULTILIB := 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Nop, you need to get the native library to be compatible with 64-bit for it to work.

See official documentation: [JNI Tips: 64-bit Considerations](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#64_bit)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't say anything like that: "For the most part this isn't something that you will need to worry about when interacting with native code". After reading that paragraph, an UnsatisfiedLinkError is the last thing I'd expect.

Comment: You might be right, but I think `UnsatisfiedLinkError` happened to me when I had your exact some problem once. I might be wrong, sorry if that's the case. Hope someone will help you out more.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, when I did the update from Android Studio 2.1 to 2.2.3 (with ndk v.13.1), and no tips found in google really helped me (like using abiFilters, exclude 'lib/x86_64/lib….so’, LOCAL_MULTILIB := 32, or TARGET_PREFER_32_BIT := true, …).

Finally, I was able to make it worked again with the latest AS v2.2.3 (without changing anything in Android.mk or in build.gradle), just by using my previous ndk compiler, i.e. android-ndk-r10e

I built the library manually with ndk-build for "armeabi-v7a" and "x86" only, and it worked like a charm on Android with arm64.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I enabled the advanced profiling feature under the build settings of the app