# Android - Skobbler doesn't support 64 bits processor

Tags: skmaps

`Skobbler` doesn't support x64 bits processors.

Is it possible to fix the x86 bits libraries to work on x64 bits device ?

```
2-02 14:55:35.171 8818-8840/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3042
12-02 14:55:35.171 8818-8840/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: am.ggtaxi.main.ggdriver, PID: 8818
12-02 14:55:35.171 8818-8840/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/am.ggtaxi.main.ggdriver-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/am.ggtaxi.main.ggdriver-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libngnative.so"
12-02 14:55:35.171 8818-8840/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
12-02 14:55:35.171 8818-8840/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
12-02 14:55:35.171 8818-8840/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.skobbler.ngx.SKMaps.<clinit>(SourceFile:59)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not plan to support this

Comment: Any news on this @SylviA? Nexus 5x and 6p mount 64 bits processors and we have the same crash... Thank you so much in advance!!!!

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186243/use-32-bit-jni-libraries-on-64-bit-android) and maybe this can be used for a workaround. What do you think @SylviA? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4):

This workaround works for me: [How to use 32-bit native libaries on 64-bit Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782848/how-to-use-32-bit-native-libaries-on-64-bit-android-device?lq=1)

Add: `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` to a file named gradle.properties at the root of your project and the following code in your gradle file:

```
    android {
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
     }
    }
```

I hope that this helps you :)