# Cordova android 64 bit fallback to 32 bit doesn't work

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have a library that doesn't support 64 bit so i read that you can just not include any 64 bit libs and it should auto fall back to 32 bit  I am set cordova to multiple apks so it produces 2 version one for arm one for x86

```
productFlavors {
        armv7 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
            }
        }
        x86 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
            ndk {
                abiFilters "x86", ""
            }
        }
        all {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "all", ""
            }
        }
```

If i unzip the arm apk and i look in lib i only see one folder named "armeabi-v7a"  but i still get a

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could find lib to load: lib.so  it's looking for a 64 bit version of lib.  The documentation of the lib i am using state that i need to have fallback support for 322 bit and a gradle.propertiesfile with android.useDeprecatedNdk=true.  i added this still no dice.

Any whelp woudl be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you loading using `load(...)` or `loadLibrary(...)` to load the libraries ? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27202958/139985

Comment: It's a hybrid app and i am a bit new to Android  I am not sure where the load / load library calls would be made the stack-overflow you referenced doesn't really say

Comment: Well I would surmise that the app is loading the libraries the wrong way ... and that the only way to get fallback to work on 32bit would involve changing the library.  If you can ... you are stuffed.

Comment: So where to i look to see what it's using Cordova is open source and the test app that doesn't use cordova works fine.  witch leads me to believe it's cordova's fault it's not working.  are these calls in the grade file the java classes?

Comment: Download the source code and grep for `load(` and `loadLibrary(`